# How to extract the URL from this javascript code

Tags: facebook, swift3

So I ran into this problem. This is my code inside my Facebook graph request

```
if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "error unknows")
                return
            }
            let resultDict = result as? NSDictionary
            let data = resultDict?["data"] as! NSArray
            for i in 0 ..< data.count
            {
                let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as! NSDictionary
                let id = valueDict.object(forKey: "id") as! String
                print("the id value is \(id)")
            }

            let friends = resultDict?.object(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
            print(friends[0] as AnyObject)
            print("Found \(friends.count)
```

This part of the code

> print(friends[0] as AnyObject)

returns:

```
{
    "first_name" = OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO;
    id = 1OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO;
    "last_name" = OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO;
    name = "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/15871714_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        };
    };
}
```

I know how to extract the name and the ID but its the image URL that im having an issue extracting. From questions I asked around this is javascript not JSON. Thanks for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know how to extract ID then you shouldn't have proble with url. Let's say you extract id by following:

```
friends[0]["id"]
```

Then to extract the url you would use:

```
friends[0]["picture"]["data"]["url"]
```

This is simply just JSON.

Comment: You're absolutely right sir. You're a rockstar! My confusion was that people told me that this was javascript and being a newbie that threw me off completely. Thank you!  I solved by going into picture as a NSDictionary, then data as NSDictionary then extracting url as String. Just as you suggested. Thank you again.